# Does a vehicle require a crew if it is enchanted to become a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, say I have a [Consulate Dreadnought](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConsulate%20Dreadnought%5d) and I enchant it with [Siege Modification](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSiege%20Modification%5d). The Crew effect makes it to become an artifact creature, but if it is already an artifact creature, does it need to be crewed to attack?

Answer (score 8):

No it does not. Siege Modification says that it's a creature in addition to its other types, so it counts as a creature for anything that cares about it being a creature, including the ability to attack with it.

This is the main point of Siege Modification's ability.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was pretty sure, but I wanted to get a second opinion before I made a fool of myself.

Comment: Another way to look at it: Siege Modifications makes the permanent a creature in addition to its other types. Crew *also* makes a Vehicle a creature in addition to its other types. If you have either one, the other doesn't do anything.

Comment: Though, You can still crew it.